# Docker, Jenkins and Rails - Setup for running specs on a typical Rails stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, jenkins

I would like a Jenkins master and slave setup for running specs on standard Rails apps (PostgreSQL, sidekiq/redis, RSPec, capybara-webkit, a common Rails stack), using docker so it can be put on other machines as well. I got a few good stationary machines collecting dust.

1. Can anybody share an executable docker jenkins rails stack example?
2. What prevents that from being done?

Preferable with master-slave setup too.

Preface:
After days online, following several tutorials with no success, I am about to abandon project. I got a basic understanding of docker, docker-machine, docker compose and volumes, I got a docker registry of a few simple apps.

Comment: Your question covers *quite* a lot, and you're unlikely to get a single answer for all of it. If I were in your shoes, I'd consider breaking it down into a question about dockerising your process, and another about setting up a docker-compose setup on Jenkins.

Working examples are also hard to provide for a description as general as the one you've provided, especially if you're looking for one that others have used first-hand with a setup very similar to yours.

All that said, I'm working on an answer for the things I can help with.

Comment: I appreciate the efforts to help. I can't really argue against the topic covering a lot, but at the same time it's nothing custom or unique, any example using standard stacks would do.

Comment: 2 days left of the 500 bounty. No answer so far has provided any executables or explained why that can't be done. As it stands, the bounty remains unclaimed.

Comment: https://github.com/joshua5201/ci-jenkins-docker-rails

Comment: https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/ruby-on-rails-continuous-integration-with-jenkins-and-docker-compose-8dfd24c3df57

Comment: Good links Tony. I did see these as well even though I didn't complete them, had some issues early on. I guess my frustration has been that all these tutorials are huge recipes of manual ops. It would be really helpful with a ready setup, a ready executable. I will give the links you provided another shot though.

Comment: I can only answer your second question: I think Docker and Ruby follow very distinct patterns that makes it hard to integrate them with each other. Docker has the concept of base images that are collections of released software packages from fixed distributions. But there is no such concept as distributions in the Ruby world. Everything is a collection of Gems that are put together according to your specifications. Therefore there are very few "base" package that could be put together and used together.

Comment: That doesn't mean it can't be done. It just means that you have to do it more or less from scratch - but if you are deploying a Rails application to a physical machine (instead of a docker image) you are facing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know next to nothing about Jenkins, but I've used Docker pretty extensively on other CI platforms. So I'll just write about that. The level of difficulty is going to vary a lot based on your app's dependencies and quirks. I'll try and give an outline that's pretty generally useful, and leave handling application quirks up to you.

I don't think the problem you describe should require you to mess about with `docker-machine`. `docker build` and `docker-compose` should be sufficient.

First, you'll need to build an image for your application. If your application has a comprehensive `Gemfile`, and not too many dependencies relating to infrastructure etc (e.g. files living in particular places that the application doesn't set up for itself), then you'll have a pretty easy time. If not, then setting up those dependencies will get complicated. Here's a [guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/#define-the-project) from the Docker folks for a simple Rails app that will help get you started.

Once the image is built, push it to a repository such as Docker Hub. Log in to Docker Hub and create a repo, then use `docker login` and `docker push <image-name>` to make the image accessible to other machines. This will be important if you want to build the image on one machine and test it on others.

*It's probably worth spinning off a job to run your app's unit tests inside the image once the image is built and pushed. That'll let you fail early and avoid wasting precious execution time on a buggy revision :)*

Next you'll need to satisfy the app's external dependencies, such as Redis and postgres. This is where the Docker Compose file comes in. Use it to specify all the services your app needs, and the environment variables etc that you'll set in order to run the application for testing (e.g. `RAILS_ENV`).

*You might find it useful to provide fakes of some non-essential services such as in-memory caches, or just leave them out entirely. This will reduce the complexity of your setup, and be less demanding on your CI system.*

The guide from the link above also has an example compose file, but you'll need to expand on it. The most important thing to note is that the name you give a service (e.g. `db` in the example from the guide) is used as a hostname in the image. As @tomwj suggested, you can search on Docker Hub for common images like postgres and Redis and find them pretty easily. You'll probably need to configure a new Rails environment with new hostnames and so on in order to get all the service hostnames configured correctly.

You're starting all your services from scratch here, including your database, so you'll need to migrate and seed it (and any other data stores) on every run. Because you're starting from an empty postgres instance, expect that to take some time. As a shortcut, you could restore a backup from a previous version before migrating. In any case, you'll need to do some work to get your data stores into shape, so that your test results give you useful information.

One of the tricky bits will be getting Capybara to run inside your application Docker image, which won't have any X displays by default. `xvfb` (X Virtual Frame Buffer) can help with this. I haven't tried it, but building on top of an image like [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/maxwellhealthofficial/docker-capybara-webkit-chromedriver/) may be of some help.

Best of luck with this. If you have the time to persist with it, it will really help you learn about what your application really depends on in order to work. It certainly did for me and my team!

Comment: That's really helpful for running my app on docker. That part is fine, I won't start with my most complex app, but the trick here is jenkins I guess. I just whish I could see some good compose files or dockerfiles. The absence of "working examples" is what is mysterious to me.

Comment: Did the guide I linked to above ( https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/#define-the-project ) not work for you? It usually works for simple Ruby/Rails apps.

Comment: Good link. However helpful, you aren't answering the question, I am also asking for executables/working examples. Jenkins is the key challenge here, and the interaction between that and docker images for it to run.

Comment: If you're after Jenkins expertise, I probably can't help you any further. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a lot to unpack in that question, this is a guide of how to get started and where to look for help.

In short there's nothing preventing it, although it's reasonably complex and bespoke to setup. So hence no off-the-shelf solution.

Assuming your aim is to have Jenkins build, deploy to Docker, then test a Rails application in a Dockerised environment.

1. Provision the stationary machines, I'd suggest using [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/) roles.

   - [Install Jenkins](https://galaxy.ansible.com/binarytemple/jenkins/)
   - [Install Docker](https://galaxy.ansible.com/mongrelion/docker/)
   - Setup a local Docker registry
2. Setup Docker environment, the way to bring up multiple containers is to use docker compose this will allow you to bring up the DB, redis, Rails etc... using the public docker hub images.
3. Create a [Jenkins pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/)

   - [Build the rails app docker image](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/#rebuild-the-application)  this will contain the rails app.
   - Deploy the application, this updates the application in the Docker swarm, from the local Docker registry.
   - Test, run the tests against the application now running.

I've left out the Jenkins master/slave config because if you're only running on one machine you can increase the number of executors. E.g. the master can execute more jobs at the expense of speed.

Comment: have you set up jenkins on docker running ruby specs?